# How to limit authorization and viewing restriction in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint site with multiple type of users(admin, simple user, manager).
I want each user to be able to see only his own list and documents and the simple user can only add a new site and access to parameters site.

Does anyone have an idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharepoint roles and permissions for this. You can also create your custom roles and permissions as per your requirements. This can be handled at various level: Site, list and also at item level.

For more information :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc262690(v=office.15).aspx

http://www.spdockit.com/blog/permissions-management-sharepoint-2013-part-one/

http://documents.software.dell.com/DOC158353